# Durrett Probability Ex2.3.4

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am getting stuck on Exercise 2.3.4 in Durret Probability 5th edition. The question is as follows:

Exercise 2.3.4 (Fatou's Lemma) Suppose $X_{n}\geq 0$ and $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in probability. Show that $\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}EX_{n}\geq EX$.

So far my approach is:

As $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in probability, there exists a subsequence $n_{k}$ such that $X_{n_{k}}\rightarrow X$ almost surly. Also, as $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in probability, for every subsequence $X_{n_{k}}$ there exists a further subsequence $X_{n_{m_{k}}}$ such that $X_{n_{m_{k}}}\rightarrow X$ almost surly.

Then, as $X_{n}\geq 0$, then $X_{n_{m_{k}}}\geq 0$ which means we can apply Fatou's Lemma to the sequence $X_{n_{m_{k}}}$:

$\lim\inf_{k\rightarrow\infty} EX_{n_{m_{k}}}\geq E(\lim\inf_{k\rightarrow\infty X_{n_{m_{k}}}})$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Or maybe my previous steps are already wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have good idea. Firstly take subsequence $(n_k)$ such that: $$\liminf_n \mathbb E[X_n] = \lim_k \mathbb E[X_{n_k}]$$ Now, take one more sub-subsequnce $(n_{k_m})$ from $(n_k)$ such that $X_{n_{k_m}} \to X$ almost surely.

Then you'll get:

$$ \liminf_n \mathbb E[X_n] = \lim_m \mathbb E[X_{n_{k_m}}] = \liminf_m \mathbb E[X_{n_{k_m}}] \ge \mathbb E[\liminf_m X_{n_{k_m}}] = \mathbb E[X]$$

Where firstly we used $(n_{k_m}) \subset (n_k)$, secondly, when $\lim$ exists, then $\liminf$ is equal to $\lim$. At point of inequality we used Fatou lemma and lastly our subsequence $(n_{k_m})$ was such that $X_{n_{k_m}} \to X$ almost surely (hence $\liminf_m X_{n_{k_m}} = X$, too)

Comment: Thank you SO much! Extremely appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome!